# Plotly multiline legend bullets vertical alignment

Tags: python, plotly

Consider the following MWE:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
for i in range(4):
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x = [1,2,3],
            y = [i]*3,
            name = 'A very long legend<br>which I break in<br>multiple lines'
        )
    )
fig.write_html('deleteme.html')
```

which produces this:
[image]

Is it possible to change the alignment of the bullets in the legend to produce this instead? (I made it with Paint)
[image]

In the previous trivial example this looks like a whim, however in more complex cases the alignment of the legend bullets makes it really confusing to know which is which:
[image]

Comment: `fig.update_layout(legend_valign='top')`

Comment: Cast your comment to an answer since it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ user171780 Thanks for inviting.

You can adjust the position of the legend with [legend_valign](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/#layout-legend-valign), with the code `fig.update_layout(legend_valign='top')`.

Furthermore, you can adjust the distance between the legend with adding group during plotting and define the distance with `legend_tracegroupgap`.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
for i in range(4):
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x = [1,2,3],
            y = [i]*3,
            name = 'A very long legend<br>which I break in<br>multiple lines',
            legendgroup = 'group' + str(i)
        )
    
    )
    
fig.update_layout(legend_valign='top')

fig.update_layout(legend_tracegroupgap=30)

fig.show()
```